# Creating shared libraries in C++ for OSX

Tags: c++, linux, macos, stl, shared-libraries

I just started programming in C++ and I've realized that I've been having to write the same code over and over again(mostly utility functions).

So, I'm trying to create a shared library and install it in PATH so that I could use the utility functions whenever I needed to.

Here's what I've done so far :-

Create a file `utils.h` with the following contents :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
std::string to_binary(int x);
```

Create a file `utils.cpp` with the following contents :-

```
#include "utils.h"

std::string to_binary(int x) {
  std::string binary = "";
  while ( x > 0 ) {
    if ( x & 1 ) binary += "1";
    else binary += "0";
    x >>= 1;
  }
  return binary;
}
```

Follow the steps mentioned here :-
http://www.techytalk.info/c-cplusplus-library-programming-on-linux-part-two-dynamic-libraries/

- Create the library object code : `g++ -Wall -fPIC -c utils.cpp`

But as the link above is meant for Linux it does not really work on OSX. Could someone suggest reading resources or suggest hints in how I could go about compiling and setting those objects in the path on an OSX machine?

Also, I'm guessing that there should be a way I can make this cross-platform(i.e. write a set of instructions(bash script) or a Makefile) so that I could use to compile this easily across platforms. Any hints on that?

Comment: Only semi-relevant, but converting an `int` to a string of `0`s and `1`s is easier via `std::bitset`: `std::string to_binary(int v) { return std::bitset<sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT>(v).to_string();}`

Comment: You don't need to install your `libuki.so` in your `$PATH` but just in your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (e.g. perhaps in your `$HOME/lib/`)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `-dynamiclib` option to compile a dynamic library on OS X:

```
g++ -dynamiclib -o libutils.dylib utils.cpp
```

And then use it in your client application:

```
g++ client.cpp -L/dir/ -lutils
```

Comment: You should probably set `install_name` on `libutils.dylib` once installed

Answer (score 11):

The link you posted is using C and the C compiler.  Since you are building C++:

```
g++ -shared -o libYourLibraryName.so utils.o
```

Comment: You really want to pass `-fPIC` also at least on Linux

Comment: You should use `-dynamiclib` option on OS X instead of `-shared`.

Comment: @linuxbuild what is the difference? (Landed here mid-Googling)

Comment: @monkey0506 -dynamiclib: When passed this option, GCC produces a dynamic library instead of an executable when linking, using the Darwin libtool command.

Comment: @linuxbuild "GCC produces a dynamic library instead of an executable when linking" so you're saying that if "-shared" is used rather than "-dynamiclib" (on OS X) then GCC will produce an executable, rather than a dynamic library? I'm asking what the difference is because in my experience there isn't any.

Comment: @monkey0506 I have the same observation, however the difference might be in the library linker, eg `-dynamiclib` will uses macOs specific `libtool`, but I'm not sure about what gcc does with `-shared`.