# How to create a shared library (.so) file in Mac os X using terminal

Tags: macos

How to create a shared library (.so) file in Mac os X  using terminal

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create it from what?  And why can't you use Xcode?

Comment: I have source file like .cpp file i need to create .o file  by compiling that .cpp  file and based on that .o file i want to create .so file. how to create .o file ?

Comment: Is that shared library is .so file or .dylib on mac OSX ? which one i should use, can you please anyone guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating shared libraries in C++ for OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173260/creating-shared-libraries-in-c-for-osx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in the directory with your .cpp/.c and .h files, in the terminal you must type:

1. g++ -c file1.cpp file2.cpp (add as many cpp/c files you want in the so file)
2. g++ *.o -dynamiclib -o lib_name.so

Then if you are using a cpp file that will run it:

3. g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o (compiling the program to see if the shared library works)
4. g++ -o test test.o -L. -l_name (create an executable to run)
5. ./test (run the test)

For C code so files, it's the same but replace g++ with gcc.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have tested this procedure on MacOS, right? (I'm asking because OP was explicit about needing a MacOS answer, not a generic *nix answer.)